# Json schema validation : required attributes based on attributes from different object in same json

Tags: json, schema, json-schema-validator

I have a requirement where i need to define attribute in one object as required based on value of attribute in another object.

e.g

```
  {
      "if" : {
        "properties" : {
          "Status" : {
            "const" : "CANCELLED"
          }
        },
        "required" : [
          "Status"
        ]
      },
      "then" : {
        "required" : [
          "Reason"
        ]
      }
    }
```

above condition works. However below e.g doesn't work

```
 {
      "if" : {
        "properties" : {
          "#/Details/HasAgreement" : {
            "const" : true
          }
        },
        "required" : [
          "#/Details/HasAgreement"
        ]
      },
      "then" : {
        "required" : [
          "#/Contract/EffectiveDate"
        ]
      }
    }
```

I'm guessing that the way how I'm referring attributes from different objects in same json is wrong. what is the right way?

Thanks,
Madhu